# Should I go out of my way to avoid spoilers in my questions?

Tags: discussion

When I ask any question whether it's here or in real life, I will always try to lay down a foundation on what I'm asking about just to give context to anyone who could answer.  This tends to make my questions look long to anyone who wouldn't give a damn about what I'm talking about.

I've asked a question very recently that was closed for being unclear apparently by people who haven't played the game and has no idea what I was talking about. (another issue that I won't go into here)

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272969/why-am-i-able-to-breathe-underwater-indefinitely-now

The way it was phrased was a product of me trying very hard not to spoil what happens in the game.  Granted, even if you had played the game, it could be more confusing than not and I could improve it and that's what I'll do.  But I was more concerned about not spoiling the game for anyone who casually came across my question.

**Should I really go out of my way to avoid spoilers in my questions?  Or should I just ask my question and spoilers be damned?**

Comment: This isn't a duplicate. One is asking specifically about question titles. This is asking about something with slightly less visibility.

Comment: @Fluttershy - Not sure I agree.  The answers in the duplicate apply here.  See http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/10838/101016

Comment: Something in here may also be useful: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/5519/101016

Comment: @camelCase, the question asks asbout *titles*. You should not consider the answer when closing a question. Answers do not make questions dupes

Answer (score 3):

The presence of spoilers seems completely unrelated with the problem your question has. Are you... asking why you now have an ability that you yourself admit is necessary to proceed further in the game? It sounds like you have gained the ability because the developers intended you to gain this ability now.

If this was intended to be a lore question, please make it clearer. At the moment I wouldn't be surprised if the question was closed as developer intent.